# recognize back-button on dialog-service

Tags: android, xamarin, prism

I'm using the Prism- [dialog-service](https://prismlibrary.com/docs/xamarin-forms/dialogs/dialog-service.html) to show a dialog with a yes- and a no-button. This works fine. The user makes the choice and the calling page gets the dialogresult.

But it is also possible for the user to press the back-button if the dialog is present and the dialog disappears without any result to the calling page.

I know that I can override the OnBackButtonPressed-event in the MainActivity but this affects everywhere in my app.

It's important for me, that I can handle this behavior (suspend Back-Button or not) individually for each Dialog.

Therefore I'm looking for an event which will be fired if the back-button is pressed while the dialog is shown.
Similary with the OnBackButtonPressed-Event on a ContentPage.

Comment: `the dialog disappears without any result` do you mean that the callback isn't called?

Comment: the callback will only be called, if the user press the yes- or no-button on the dialog.
in case of the back-button the callback isn't called

Comment: You can override the OnBackButtonPressed-event and add a judgment which the dialog is showing or not to do different things.

Comment: in opposite to a page it isn't possible to override a OnBackButtonPressed-event in a Prism-Dialog, which is using a dialogservice, because this event is not available

Comment: What I mean is that you can override the OnBackButtonPressed-event in the MainActivity like you said and add a judgment which the dialog is showing or not to avoid affecting everywhere in your app.

Answer (score 0):

forms project - pages:

<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
.
.
IsBusy="{Binding IsBusy}">

---

android project - MainActivity:

```
    public override void OnBackPressed()
    {
        var allNotBusy = true;
        foreach (var fragment in this.GetFragmentManager().Fragments)
        {
            var contentPage = fragment.GetType().GetProperty("Page")?.GetValue(fragment) as ContentPage;

            if (contentPage.IsBusy)
            {
                allNotBusy = false;
            }
        }

        if (allNotBusy)
        {
            base.OnBackPressed();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Disable back button in all Dialogs, and if you want some back behavior, add back button to your dialog

Comment: Can you provide some more explanation on what does your code do?

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31969349)